# Calculating the area on the surface of the Earth from the intersection of two polygons using Python

Tags: python, area, list

I have made a program that calculates area and perimeter based on 2D coordinates (latitude and latitude) given by the user, asking if they want to include more coordinates from the third pair, and evaluating the area and perimeter each time a pair of coordinates is added.

Besides, it compares the values of the area and perimeter from different regions, choosing how many regions the user wants to evaluate, and I have added a zip that "joins" each latitude to its longitude value, and I have converted that zip in a list, so I can print it each time because it is in a loop (that calculates the number of areas the user wants).

Furthermore, it calculates if the regions evaluated overlap (I created polygons from the pair_coordinates_list = {}), and what area would that intersected area be.

```
from pyproj import Geod
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.wkt import dumps

geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')

regions = 0
area_list = []
perimeter_list = []
pair_coordinates_list = {}
poly = {}
while True:
    regions += 1
    lats = []
    lons = []
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        lat = float(input(f"Enter latitude #{count}: "))
        lon = float(input(f"Enter longitude #{count}: "))
        lats.append(lat)
        lons.append(lon)

        if count < 3:
            print("Not enough information to calculate the area.")
            continue

        poly_area, poly_perimeter = geod.polygon_area_perimeter(lons, lats)

        print(f"\nLatitude coordinates #{regions}: {lats}")
        print(f"Longitude coordinates #{regions}: {lons}")

        pair_coordinates = zip(lats,lons)
        type(pair_coordinates)
        pair_coordinates_list[regions - 1] = list(pair_coordinates)
        print(f"Pair of coordinates #{regions}: ", pair_coordinates_list[regions - 1])
        
        poly = geometry.Polygon (pair_coordinates_list[regions - 1])
        print(poly[regions-1])                                                 

        for info in zip(lats,lons):
            print(info)

        print(f"Area #{regions}:", (abs(float(poly_area))) / (1000000), "km^2")
        print(f"Perimeter #{regions}:", (abs(float(poly_perimeter))) / (1000), "km")
        if input('Enter more coordinates? [Y/N] ') in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'no', 'non']:
            area_list.append(poly_area)
            perimeter_list.append(poly_perimeter)
            break 
    if input('More regions? [Y/N] ') in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'no', 'non']:
        break 

while True:
    dividend = int(input("Write what region is the dividend:")) - 1
    area_km_dividend = (abs(area_list[dividend])/1000000)
    perimeter_km_dividend = (abs(perimeter_list[dividend])/1000)
    print(f"Area: {area_km_dividend}")
    print(f"Perimeter: {perimeter_km_dividend}")
    print(f"Pair of coordinates of region #{dividend + 1}: ", list(pair_coordinates_list[dividend]))

    divisor = int(input("Which region is the divisor?:")) - 1
    area_km_divisor = (abs(area_list[divisor])/1000000)
    perimeter_km_divisor = (abs(perimeter_list[divisor])/1000)
    print(f"Area: {area_km_divisor}")
    print(f"Perimeter: {perimeter_km_divisor}")
    print(f"Pair of coordinates of region #{divisor + 1}: ", list(pair_coordinates_list[divisor]))


    area_divid_div = area_km_dividend / area_km_divisor
    area_div_divid = area_km_divisor / area_km_dividend

    perimeter_divid_div = perimeter_km_dividend / perimeter_km_divisor
    perimeter_div_divid = perimeter_km_divisor / perimeter_km_dividend
    
if (poly)[dividend].intersection(poly[divisor]):
    print("\nRegions evaluated overlap on this zone:")
    poly_temp = dumps(poly[dividend].intersection(poly[divisor]), rounding_precision=3)
    print(poly_temp)
else:
    print("\nRegions do not overlap")
     
    if area_divid_div > 1:
        print(f"\nArea of region #{dividend + 1} is", area_divid_div*100 - 100, f"% larger than #{divisor + 1}")
        if perimeter_divid_div > 1:
            print(f"Perimeter of region #{dividend + 1} is", perimeter_divid_div*100 - 100, f"% larger than #{divisor + 1}")
        else:
            print(f"Perimeter of region #{divisor + 1} es un", perimeter_div_divid*100 - 100, f"% larger than #{dividend + 1}")
    else:
        print(f"\nArea of region #{divisor + 1} is", (area_div_divid*100) - 100, f"% larger than #{dividend + 1}")
        if perimeter_divid_div > 1:
            print(f"Perimeter of region #{dividend + 1} is", perimeter_divid_div*100 - 100, f"% larger than #{divisor + 1}")
        else:
            print(f"Perimeter of region  #{divisor + 1} is", perimeter_div_divid*100 - 100, f"% larger than #{dividend + 1}")

    if input('Do you want to evaluate more regions? [Y/N] ') in ['n', 'N', 'No', 'no', 'non']:
        break
```

It returns a Polygon, which is a list, with two coordinates (latitude and longitude). How can I calculate area from that?